# log4j File appender not working with eclipse

Tags: java, log4j

I have a webservice program which has multiple classes talking to each other.

After running the program using tomcat in eclipse, I copy the wsdl url in soap UI to test it out and if there's any exception then it has to be in printed in a log file as I am file appender logic from log4j. Spent almost three days with no luck

Here is log4j.properties file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE, theConsoleAppender
log4j.category.com.wataniya.Wataniya_WebServiceSkeleton=DEBUG, FILE

### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.txt

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern= %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c %p %t %m%n%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imported the required jar files in to build path in eclipse. More info can be found at  this link in importing the jar files and configuring the properties file: [Link](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-configuration.html)